# Массив случайных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Как создать `numpy` массив со случайными числами из заданного интервала?

Comment: с дубликатами или без?

Comment: можно с дубликатами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день. Можно так:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(50, 60, size=(2, 10))
print(array)
```

Если же вы хотите сделать массив из float значений, то нужно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
array = np.random.uniform(4, 5, [2, 10])
print(array)
```

Если не планируется использовать размерность больше одного, то можно записать следующую констуркцию:

```
array = np.random.randint(50, 60, 10) # для int
```

Или

```
array = np.random.uniform(4, 5, 10) # для float
```

Comment: Потестил, с `numpy` в разы быстрее, буду вникать :)

Answer (score 0):

К примеру список случайных чисел можно создать без участия `numpy`

```
>>> a = [random.choice([i for i in range(100)]) for j in range(111)]
>>> a
[9, 49, 34, 36, 74, 53, 41, 70, 46, 76, 12, 76, 81, 34, 95, 24, 43, 43, 84, 45, 32, 23, 56, 11, 12, 34, 97, 39, 21, 66, 68, 0, 79, 28, 62, 68, 86, 16, 91, 20, 78, 56, 96, 97, 10, 60, 57, 20, 44, 2, 29, 8, 17, 27, 11, 76, 24, 59, 71, 40, 18, 30, 25, 40, 55, 17, 94, 34, 35, 4, 39, 41, 88, 68, 1, 15, 34, 99, 95, 36, 98, 49, 52, 12, 69, 46, 64, 20, 33, 90, 27, 32, 26, 48, 3, 87, 38, 10, 83, 93, 5, 81, 37, 2, 71, 85, 10, 64, 60, 3, 30]
```